# How to output in an array to template?

Tags: php

The idea is this:
There is a page on it there is a post search request in ajax.php, which sends a request to the external API and receives an array

Code ajax.php:

```
$url = 'http://domen.ru/api/search.php';
$params = array(
    'search' => $_POST['search'],
    'key' => $secret_key,
);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => http_build_query($params)
    )
)));
$result = json_decode($result, true);
```

Further in this ajax.php check for $result and output (which I can’t do):

```
if ($result) {
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        $id = $value['id'];
        $date = $value['date'];
        $title = $value['title'];
        $thumb = $value['thumb'];
        include '../tpl/remotePostSearch.tpl';
    }
}
```

Accordingly, the whole idea is to pass a two-dimensional array (for example):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Coffe
            [date] => 30/04/2020
            [id] => 5
            [thumb] => /32894e4b.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Tea
            [date] => 30/04/2020
            [id] => 4
            [thumb] => 1528900394_clash-of-clans.png
        )

)
```

into the template and display it in its normal form via the .tpl template:

```
<h2><?=$title?></h2>
<div>
<img src="http://domen.ru/images/<?=$thumb?>">
<p><?=$id?> :: <?=$date?></p>
</div>
```

But it turns out it is not clear that.
Where is the error and how to implement such a conclusion?
ajax.php for output should generate HTML code based on the TPL file

Comment: `.tpl` is not processed by php?

Comment: only one result and foreach output {* *} {* *} {* *} but not values

Comment: Can you show us an example `$result` string?

Comment: in $result array
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Coffe
            [date] => 30/04/2020
            [id] => 5
            [thumb] => /32894e4b.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Tea
            [date] => 30/04/2020
            [id] => 4
            [thumb] => 1528900394_clash-of-clans.png
        )

)

after: 
"{*
*} {* *} {* /32894e4b.jpg*} {*"

Comment: var_export() would be a better formatter than var_dump() because we can directly use the data.

Comment: There could be path issue with your `include '../tpl/remotePostSearch.tpl';` call. Please change it to `require '../tpl/remotePostSearch.tpl';` and see if there is any error.

Comment: changed, but the problem remained